# Why weakening rule doesn't increase the size of resolution refutation?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, induction

I am studying the complexity of SAT resolution refutation. There is a useful tool named weakening rule

> T[he weakening rule](https://www.csc.kth.se/%7Ejakobn/teaching/proofcplx11/lectures/ScribeNotesLec02.pdf):
> B -->B ∨ C
> says that from a clause B we can derive the weaker clause B ∨ C for an arbitrary C. We say
> that B ∨ C is a weakening of B.
> We can add this extra rule without loss of generality, since any applications of weakening in
> a resolution refutation can always be eliminated.

**My question:** Why weakening rule doesn't increase the size of resolution refutation?

where size means the number of clauses the refutation contained.

Ituitively, I can understand it, but I can't state the proof formally.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to define what you mean by the "size" of resolution refutation.  Please add your thoughts and understanding.  What progress have you made?

Comment: Theorem 2 solves my problem. https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/CourseWeb/Math267_2002W/lecture7.pdf